# Kraken.js dust view engine

Tags: node.js, dust.js, kraken.js

I am using Kraken.js with Dust as the default view engine. I get this error:

> No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.    at
>   new View
>   (/home/zhiro/Desktop/kraken/krakil/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:62:11)
>   at EventEmitter.render
>   (/home/zhiro/Desktop/kraken/krakil/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:569:12)
>   at ServerResponse.render
>   (/home/zhiro/Desktop/kraken/krakil/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
>   at /home/zhiro/Desktop/kraken/krakil/controllers/index.js:14:13    at
>   Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (/home/zhiro/Desktop/kraken/krakil/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>   at next
>   (/home/zhiro/Desktop/kraken/krakil/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
>   at Route.dispatch
>   (/home/zhiro/Desktop/kraken/krakil/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (/home/zhiro/Desktop/kraken/krakil/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>   at
>   /home/zhiro/Desktop/kraken/krakil/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
>   at Function.process_params
>   (/home/zhiro/Desktop/kraken/krakil/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)

I see this error when I call `res.render`.

```
'use strict';

var IndexModel = require('../models/index');

module.exports = function (router) {
    var model = new IndexModel();
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Kraken doesn't configure a default view engine. The view engine tells Express how it should attempt to render files if it doesn't have a renderer explicitly defined for that file extension.

When you configure a new project using `yo kraken`, one of the questions it asks is what you would like your default view engine to be, but it sounds like you chose `None` on that step.

To set the default view engine, you simply pass it as part of the config object when instantiating Kraken. You can read about this in the Kraken README, under the heading [Configuration-Based Express Settings](https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-js#configuration-based-express-settings):

> Set the view engine property to the one of the view engines property names (see the section [View Engine Configuration](https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-js#view-engine-configuration)) to enable it for template rendering.

```
{
  "express": {
    [...]
    "view engine": null, // set this to "dust"
    [...]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much...
I started new project, and in command line I did choose dust (makara 2).
After that render works perfect!!! 
Now I'm looking for a books about kraken.js, but I didn't find anyone, so if you know any book about, please tell me. Thanks!